# Display text under cursor in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to create text under the cursor in my javafx application. It should look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492167/display-text-under-cursor). How do I do this?

Comment: **setToolTip(ToolTip)** is maybe what you are looking for. Try http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tooltip.htm for detailed help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a tooltip according to mouse position? - JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159182/how-to-display-a-tooltip-according-to-mouse-position-javafx)

Comment: I used your solution and got floating tooltips in my desktop Aakash.

Comment: It looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/32bkw2krlzl4pe6/atStackTools.png?dl=0) now

Comment: Can you explain why the tooltips don't disappear?

Comment: Look at this ..try the second answer for convenience https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854301/how-to-control-the-javafx-tooltips-delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX Tooltip is the UI component used to display additional information for another component when you move the mouse over the surface of the component.

```
TextField field_userName= new TextField();

Tooltip tooltip_userName=new Tooltip("Enter user name");

// Set tooltip
field_userName.setTooltip(tooltip_userName);

// Or using Tooltip.install
Tooltip.install(field_userName, tooltip_userName);

// Uninstall tooltip
Tooltip.uninstall(field_userName, tooltip_userName);
```